# Создание просто QR reader на Windows 10 UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10, qr

Необходимо сделать простой ридер QR кода для мобильного приложения под Windows 10. С того что нашёл - zxing не работает с UWP. Возможно есть другие библиотеки и решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[zxing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net) совместим с Windows Runtime компонентом (Windows 8.1 - WinRT.dll). Его можно использовать и с приложениями UWP.

Устанавливаете nugget пакет ZXing.Net.Mobile, добавляете пространство имен ZXing.Mobile.
И далее что-то вроде такого кода:

```
private MobileBarcodeScanner _scanner;
_scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(this.Dispatcher);
_scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
_scanner.TopText = "Держите камеру вертикально";
_scanner.BottomText = "Сканирование кода";
var result = await _scanner.Scan();
string message = "";
message = (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text)) ? result.Text : "Сканирование было отменено";
```